# Angular 2 How to preselect an option in select if ngModel value is null

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code which populates correctly. But how do I preselect my "None" option if orderDetail.people value is null? At the moment I just get all the options with a blank option preselected.

```
<select id="people" [(ngModel)]="orderDetail.people" name="people" #people>
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of people" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `value="null"` in your first option?

Comment: Try changing `value=""` for  `[ngValue]="null"`

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try. Huh I'm confused someone just deleted the post down below.

Comment: Thanks @Supamiu that worked :)

Comment: Oh sorry @Supamiu that doesn't seem to work for multiple select dropdowns only if there is one on the page.

Comment: have you changed `value="{{item.id}}"` for `[ngValue]="{{item.id}}"` too?